# Meaning of これでおしまいに？ in this context

Tags: meaning

Context: 18:40 to 19:10 from video below

http://up.b9dm.com/index.php/video/index/87933/series/1/plid/2813

I don't understand what the person speaking who says 「これでおしまいに？」 is referring to.

The two people afterwards both respond with まさか (i.e. they are denying what the previous person said), and then say that he (the king) has become a king who is able to forgive.

My problem is that I really have no idea what is being referred to by これでおしまい. What is he suggesting is coming to an end or is over?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but from the context I feel 1) これでおしまい refers to this affair including the punishment process (punch), and 2) まさか in this case is not actually denying anything.

まさか is often translated as "It can't be!", "Impossible!", etc., because this adverb is usually used in negative sentences. In this case, however, these old men are obviously welcoming the King and Queen's decision, so I think this まさか is working as an interjection like "(Considering the King's usual attitude,) This was improbable, but it actually happened!"

If I'm not mistaken, English "No way!" also can work in both ways (i.e., "Impossible!" and "Incredible!"), although I don't know if this fits this context.